# How to track daily and weekly active users using Redis?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, statistics, redis

I would like to track how many users login to my app per day/week.
I am trying something like that:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
     if @session.save
       ...
       REDIS.sadd "2013-02-27:activity", current_user.id
     end
  end
end
```

But how to render(save to file) weekly stats?

How to get a summary all day from current week?

Maybe I am using the wrong REDIS command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you've captured the data into one key per day, you would need to create a task to run regularly to generate aggregates for weekly and monthly counts.  Could be as simple as a small ruby script that you run daily via cron.

```
REDIS.get "#{1.day.ago.to_s}:activity" + REDIS.get "#{2.day.ago.to_s}:activity" + ...
```

(above code is just to get you started, not directly usable).

You might also want to look at `ZUNIONSTORE` (http://redis.io/commands/zunionstore)